# Dúvida sobre comando SELECT usando IN

Tags: mysql

Estou montando um select no MySQL da seguinte forma:

```
select lista, 
 (select if (count(login.LogID) > 0, 'S', 'N') from login where login.LogID = 407 and login.LogID in (11,157,66,158,407)) as Seguindo
from Comentarios
```

Se eu executo esse select no meu banco ele retorna `'S'` no campo `Seguindo`, porém se eu substituo o meu `in` da seguinte forma:

```
select lista, 
 (select if (count(login.LogID) > 0, 'S', 'N') from login where login.LogID = 407 and login.LogID in (lista)) as Seguindo
from Comentarios
```

Onde `Lista` é um campo da tabela `comentarios` com o conteúdo `11,157,66,158,407`, o MySQL retorna como `N` no campo `Seguindo`.

O meu campo `lista` é do tipo `varchar`. Alguém saberia me informar o porquê desse comportamento? E como seria possível contornar isso?

Answer (score 0):

Vamos por partes

1º SQL

```
select lista, 
 (select if (count(login.LogID) > 0, 'S', 'N') from login where login.LogID = 407 and login.LogID in (11,157,66,158,407)) as Seguindo
from Comentarios
```

Funciona corretamente pois você valida seu `LogID` dentro de uma lista de inteiros `(11,157,66,158,407)`.

2º SQL

```
select lista, 
 (select if (count(login.LogID) > 0, 'S', 'N') from login where login.LogID = 407 and login.LogID in (lista)) as Seguindo
from Comentarios
```

Não funciona pois como você disse o campo `lista` é um `varchar`, logo quando você passar ele no `in` desta forma `(lista)` o campo está sendo entendido como um valor da lista apenas, e não vários valores.

**Entenda**

Possui 5 itens na lista: `(11,157,66,158,407)` ou `('11','157','66','158','407')`
Possui 1 item na lista: `('11,157,66,158,407')`

> Cada valor de uma lista é uma linha retornada de um `select`

**Para contornar isso tu pode fazer da seguinte forma**

```
select lista, 
 (select if (count(login.LogID) > 0, 'S', 'N') from login where login.LogID = 407 and  FIND_IN_SET(login.LogID, lista)) as Seguindo
from Comentarios
```

Se quiser saber mais sobre o [FIND_IN_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, você disse que o conteúdo da tabela Comentario é `11,157,66,158,407`, se você quis dizer que ao fazer o select nesta tabela ele retorna somente 1 linha com este valor, então o problema é esse, você não esta passando uma lista na sua condição `in` do select.

Agora, se ao fazer o select ele te retorna 5 linhas e cada linha com um valor, assim:

```
linha 1 -> 11;  
linha 2 -> 157;  
linha 3 -> 66;  
linha 4 -> 158;  
linha 5 -> 407;
```

Você pode montar seu select assim:

```
select lista, 
 (select if (count(login.LogID) > 0, 'S', 'N') from login where login.LogID = 407 and login.LogID in (select lista from comentarios)) as Seguindo
from Comentarios
```

Veja aqui um [exemplo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d0e453/3) do select acima.